# JQuery : Delete span from title tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please how can I get a span into title tag i try to use

```
console.log($('title > span').text());
```

but it return an empty result. For example I want to get the word beautiful from this code :

```
<title>lorem epsum dolor <span class="spa">beautiful</span></title>
```

Comment: Why would you *want* to nest a `<span>`, or any other element, within a `<title>` element? And, incidentally, your question body and its title don't seem to agree with each other; what is it you want to do?

Comment: Putting a span in a title won't process the span... it will just appear as text, not HTML (at least in IE 11).

Comment: @DavidThomas the purpose of the spam tag is to make difference between male and female, I'll use adjectives between span tag.

Answer (score 7):

`<title>` tag should not include any-other tags inside it.

as stated here https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2

> Titles may contain character entities (for accented characters, special characters, etc.), but may not contain other markup (including comments).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('title span').html()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

As Nate mentioned, a span tag is not valid within a title tag.  However, if you still need to process it for whatever reason (for instance, a dynamically generated title from a database), you could use a regular expression.

```
<script>
    var titleTag = $('title').text();
    var match = titleTag.match(/<span>(.+)<\/span>/);
    console.log(match[1]);
</script>
```